# Push content if lines wrap in FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm trying to write some code utilizing FPDF in PHP. How do I push content below if my multicell element containing text string will wrap?

https://iili.io/JHAWrJ.png

Comment: The question is not clear bur maybe the script [Table with MultiCells](http://www.fpdf.org/?go=script&id=3) can help.

Comment: Thanks @Oliver, I was actually started to think that I needed some sort of a function for this. This should work!